# XML Deserialization with Servicestack.Text

Tags: c#, servicestack, xml-deserialization

I am learning [Servicestack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) Library as it has some of the best features.I am trying to deserialize XML into one of my DTOs as below;

**C# Code:**[Relevant Code with Console Application Here]

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "http://static.cricinfo.com/rss/livescores.xml";
            WebClient w = new WebClient();
            string xml = w.DownloadString(str);
            Response rss = xml.FromXml<Response>();
            foreach (var item in rss.rss.Channel.item)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.title);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

You can go through the XML file at `str`[Given in the program]. I have prepared DTOs for the deserialization. They are as below:

```
public  class Response
{
   public RSS rss { get; set; }
}

public class RSS
{
   public string Version { get; set; }
   public ChannelClass Channel { get; set; }
}

public class ChannelClass
{
   public string title { get; set; }
   public string ttl { get; set; }
   public string description { get; set; }
   public string link { get; set; }
   public string copyright { get; set; }
   public string language { get; set; }
   public string pubDate { get; set; }
   public List<ItemClass> item { get; set; }
}

public class ItemClass
{
   public string title { get; set; }
   public string link { get; set; }
   public string description { get; set; }
   public string guid { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the program, I get an exception as shown below:

[image]

So, to change the `Element` and the `namespace`, I did following workaround:

I put the `DataContractAttribute` on my `Response` class as below:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public  class Response
{
   public RSS rss { get; set; }
}
```

I changed the `Element` name as below by adding following two lines just before deserializing

```
  //To change rss Element to Response as in Exception
  xml = xml.Replace("<rss version=\"2.0\">","<Response>");
  //For closing tag
  xml = xml.Replace("</rss>","</Response>");
```

But, it gave another exception on the foreach loop as the deserialized `rss` object was `null`. So, how should I deserialize it in a proper way using `Servicestack.Text`?

**Note :**

I know well how to deserialize with other libraries, I want to do it with ServiceStack only.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**TLDR:** Use `XmlSerializer` to deserialize from xml dialects you can't control; `ServiceStack` is designed for code-first development and **can not** be adapted to general purpose xml parsing.

---

ServiceStack.Text does *not* implement a custom Xml serializer - it uses `DataContractSerializer` under the hood.  `FromXml` is merely syntactic sugar.

### Using `DataContractSerializer` to parse Xml

As you've noticed, `DataContractSerializer` is picky about **namespaces**.  One approach is to specify the namespace explicitly on the class, but if you do this, you'll need to specify `[DataMember]` everywhere since it assumes that if anything is explicit, everything is.  You can work around this problem using an assembly-level attribute (e.g. in AssemblyInfo.cs) to declare a default namespace:

```
[assembly: ContractNamespace("", ClrNamespace = "My.Namespace.Here")]
```

This solves the namespace issue.

However, you cannot solve 2 other issues with DataContractSerializer:

- It will not use attributes (in your case, `version`)
- It requires that collections such as `item` have both a wrapping name and an element name (something like items and item)

You cannot work around these limitations because **`DataContractSerializer` is not a general-purpose XML parser**.  It is intended to easily produce and consume an API, not map arbitrary XML onto a .NET datastructure.  You will never get it to parse rss; so therefore ServiceStack.Text (which just wraps it) can also not parse it.

Instead, use `XmlSerializer`.

### Using `XmlSerializer`

This is rather straighforward.  You can parse input with something along the lines of:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RSS));
RSS rss = (RSS)serializer.Deserialize(myXmlReaderHere);
```

The trick is to annotate the various fields such that they match your xml dialect.  For example, in your case that would be:

```
[XmlRoot("rss")]
public class RSS
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string version { get; set; }
    public ChannelClass channel { get; set; }
}

public class ChannelClass
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string ttl { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string copyright { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
    public string pubDate { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public List<ItemClass> item { get; set; }
}

public class ItemClass
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string guid { get; set; }
}
```

So some judicious attributes suffice to get it to parse the XML as you want.

In summary: you **cannot** use ServiceStack for this since it uses `DataContractSerializer`.ServiceStack/`DataContractSerializer` are designed for scenarios where you control the schema.  **Use `XmlSerializer` instead.**

Comment: You mean I have no way to do this with `servicestack`?

Comment: You cannot use ServiceStack.Text for this.  But realize that servicestack's focus is web services; in particular services you provide.  The .net framework has a fine xml serializer already; it just uses that.  Using servicestack only for its XML serialization just doesn't add much - you could implement `FromXml<>` in just a few lines of code - it's not much more than `new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T)).ReadObject(reader)`.  So it's nice to have if you're using servicestack anyhow, but it's hardly a critical feature.

Comment: ServiceStack.Text can do this with JSON, however -- and quite easily.

Comment: @DanEsparza ...sure, but, well, RSS isn't JSON?

Comment: @EamonNerbonne *sheepish grin* ... that'll teach me to pay attention

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. Since you are using the [DataContract] attribute. You must include the DTOs properties with the [DataMember] Attribute or they will be skipped in the serialization/deserialization process. Use the assembly attribute as specified in [XML deserializing only works with namespace in xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689711/servicestack-xml-deserializing-only-works-with-namespace-in-xml)
2. Your xml manipulation needs to change to wrap the rss inside a response instead or replacing it.

   `xml = xml.Replace("<rss version=\"2.0\">", "<Response><rss version=\"2.0\">");`
3. I would recommend building an test Response object yourself, serlialize it to XML using ServiceStack's .ToXml() method to see the format it is expecting. You will see service stack handles the channel items as a child list of items that is not how the RSS formats the channel items. You would have to wrap all your items into a node called `<ItemClass>`

Comment: 1. Tried it and still same result 2. I failed to understand it 3.The structure you have suggested is the same as I have put in the question , isn't it?

Comment: Make sure you have the correct casing on your properties. You will need to change "Channel" to "channel". Also see this gist https://gist.github.com/jokecamp/4979703 for how ServiceStack will serialize your DTOs when you use the assembly: ContractNamespace attribute.

Comment: If I am wrong with some casing then , they should be null only, right? I am getting whole rss object null.

Comment: I updated the gist to include some test code https://gist.github.com/jokecamp/4979703. Compare it with yours and run mine.

Comment: Thanks but it is not working. It is not deserializing it properly, it gives null values of version and channel only