# WebAPI Enabling JSON support on Windows Server 2012 IIS 8

Tags: json, vb.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a new .Net webapi app that works fine on my development box but I can't get it running on our IIS8 server. The webapi can return data in XML format through a browser or through the application, but when I switch to MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json") then I just get the 500 Internal server error response from IIS.

So far in IIS 8 I have:
Added a .json Mime Type (application/json)
Installed classic ASP (seemded to need this for the next step)
Added a *.json Handler Mapping (*.json / C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll / JSON)

If anyone can give me any clues as to what I've missed that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: At the moment I'ave had to switch to XML, but that wasn't straightforward because I got the error  Expecting element 'SqlReferenceData' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/arbEvolveModel.webApi'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'SqlReferenceData', namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/arbEvolveWebAPI.webApi'.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I've had to switch to XML because time was against me. But that wasn't straightforward because I got the error
Expecting element 'SqlReferenceData' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/arbEvolveModel.webApi'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'SqlReferenceData', namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/arbEvolveWebAPI.webApi'. 
To get around this I had to add a ContractNamespace into both the web api project and the client app. Both references were slightly different as they had to convert their own namespace to a generic namespace. So for reference I had to use   and  . 
Thanks to [XML deserializing only works with namespace in xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689711/xml-deserializing-only-works-with-namespace-in-xml) for the guidance here.
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved this by running the client (it's a VB WPF client) on the server. By doing this I could see the full error message which told me the server was missing a DLL - not sure why this hadn't come up on the XML downloads. Once the error was fixed then the steps above had allowed JSON to work. Hooray!